Who were the people who would make hachlatas in their hearts and be careful to keep them
BH
Our teacher told us once that there were certain people from the Gemara correct me If I’m wrong that if they made a hachlata (decision) in their minds to do something they would do it. Would this have the status of a vow? Either way where does it talk about this? Who where these people? And is their a source for this in Shulchan Aruch?

What kind of hachlata? The story of Rav safra in Makkos 24A (rashi there) is one instance.

(1) "And is their a source for this in Shulchan Aruch?" I think it was done as a Minhag Chasidut (in the sense of acting beyond the letter of the law). (2) "Either way where does it talk about this?" i don't know about specific people who did this, but Orchot Tzadikim, Sha'ar ha-Emet ("On Truth") talks about this, starting mainly from this section.
